# what does "The methods and constructors of objects created by a class loader may reference other classes" mean?

Tags: java, jvm

The content in the question ("The methods and constructors of objects created by a class loader may reference other classes")  is quoted from the [JavaDoc of ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#resolveClass(java.lang.Class)).

Although there is an example following it, I still can't understand. Could you please give me an example which will cause error because of this?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The methods and constructors of objects created by a class loader may
>   reference other classes"*

This simply means that a class might have references to other classes. Thus, the classloader has to take care of loading the referenced classes as well.

Let's define two simple classes. A class `TestReference` with a method `foo`:

```java
public class TestReference {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

and a class `TestClass` instantiating `TestReference` in its constructor:

```java
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass() {
        TestReference reference = new TestReference();
        reference.foo();
    }
}
```

Now we define a custom classloader which loads classes from `.class` files:

```java
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // Ignore this for the example as Object is always implicitly referenced by a class
        if("java.lang.Object".equals(name)) {
            return super.loadClass(name);
        }
        System.out.println("Loading class: " + name);

        // Load class from "/path/to/my/classes/TestClass.class"
        Path fileLocation = Paths.get("/path/to/my/classes/" + name + ".class");
        try {
            byte[] classData = Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation);
            Class<?> clazz = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
            // Class has been successfully loaded and defined by the classloader
            System.out.println("Loaded: " + clazz.getSimpleName());
            return clazz;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Class could not be found
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

Compile `TestReference.java` and `TestClass.java` using `javac` for instance and move only `TestClass.class` to `/path/to/my/classes/`

> *"To determine the class(es) referred to, the Java virtual machine invokes the loadClass method of the class loader that originally created the class."*

The following will fail, as the classloader transitively tries to find and load `TestReference.class` but it will not find it at the specified location:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = new MyClassLoader();
    try {
        Object o = classLoader.loadClass("TestClass").newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Loading class: TestClass
Loaded: TestClass
Loading class: TestReference
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestReference
```

To fix this error, move `TestReference.class` to `/path/to/my/classes/` and adapt the classloader's `loadClass` as follows:

```
if("java.lang.Object".equals(name) ||
   "java.lang.System".equals(name) || 
   "java.io.PrintStream".equals(name)) {
    return super.loadClass(name);
}
```